# Customize Cucumber report in Jenkins to separate tests runnings

Tags: jenkins, cucumber

I have Jenkins job, customized through Jenkinsfile. There are few stages: running tests, rerun failed scenarios, generate cucumber report. I want separate run and rerun statistics in final report, like in this image:
[wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9ufr.png)

But in my report all results in one table: 
[actual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVIfT.png)

Jenkinsfile fragment for report generating (I use cucumber-report plugin):

```
 cucumber buildStatus: "UNSTABLE",
          jsonReportDirectory: 'target',
          trendsLimit: 7,
          skipEmptyJSONFiles: true,
          mergeFeaturesWithRetest: true,
          mergeFeaturesById: true,
          stopBuildOnFailedReport: false
```

Do you have any suggestions?
thanks

Comment: have you tried with `mergeFeaturesWithRetest: false` option?

Comment: Yes, i did. Actually, i found out, result what i want may be achieved only by changing in original source code.